# Наследование: Нет доступа к наследуемым классам и интерфейсам

Tags: java, наследование

Есть у меня в одном пакете три класса: AchievementService, AchievementServiceImpl и AbstractHealthService.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видим, интерфейс, класс и абстрактный класс.

Я пытаюсь расшириться от абстрактного класса и унаследоваться от интерфейса:

```
@Service
public class AchievementServiceImpl extends AbstractHealthService implements AchievementsService {
}
```

AbstractHealthService:

```
public abstract class AbstractHealthService {

    @Autowired
    private AuthUtils authUtils;
}
```

AchievementsService:

```
public interface AchievementsService {

    Object get(Long id);
}
```

Мне подчёркивает красным и пишет: Cannot access AbstractHealthService.
Объясните, почему так и что делать.

Comment: Классы находятся в одном пакете?

Comment: да, всё в одном

Comment: А покажите код. Для данного случая просто объявлений классов с пакетами должно быть достаточно.

Comment: обновил вопрос.

Comment: Спасибо! Можете еще пакеты с импортами указать для верности? Еще хотел спросить: почему в заголовке «Cannot access interface», а в вопросе «Cannot access AbstractHealthService»?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У меня такое было два раза - когда создаёшь абсолютно безопасное наследование и тут такое.

Проблема, оказывается, в том, что IDEA кэширует информацию о классах и может подставить устаревшую информацию о классе с таким же именем, который был когда-то создан и потом удалён.

Лечится обновлением кэша, в случае с gradle это `clean / classes`.